# How can I ensure that my static ip address is read from /etc/network/interfaces rather than dhcp?

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp

This is a follow up to the [following question](https://superuser.com/questions/764123/trying-to-reset-local-ip-address-with-a-script-that-edits-etc-network-interface/764127#764127). I'm trying to set a static IP by changing `/etc/network/interfaces` to the following:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.2.133
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.2.1
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

and then running `/sbin/ifdown eth0; /sbin/ifup eth0`. However, the change in IP address doesn't appear to take effect without editing `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` and commenting out the following before running `ifdown; ifup`:

```
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
        domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
        dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search,
        netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
        rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers,
        dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers;
```

Strangely, after commenting out this line, running `ifdown; ifup` works, but when I uncomment it, the behavior does not revert to the previous behavior of ignoring changes to my settings in `/etc/network/interfaces` (this doesn't seem like a problem, but I really need to be able to repeat this problem so that I can be confident that my solution is robust) Also, I'd rather not have to edit `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` to change my static IP since it seems I should be able to do this by only editing `interfaces`.

Can anyone explain the issues I'm seeing above and suggest the best way of making changes to static IP addresses take effect that admits reproducibility so that I can be sure that my approach works?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that `dhclient` isn't still running, and issuing an ip to `eth0` when it comes back up.

Check for `dhclient`:

```
ps aux | grep dhclient
```

If running, kill it, then perform `ifdown; ifup`.

Comment: Do you know how I can reproduce the issue I was having previously? I'd like to get back into the state I was in previously, where setting the static IP address had no effect so that I can be sure that this approach works.

Comment: Figured it out. I can't remember exactly the previous state I was in, but I can somewhat reproduce by calling `sudo ip addr flush dev eth0; sudo dhclient eth0`. Then I execute `ifdown; ip addr flush dev eth0; ifup` to load whatever static ip is set in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Answer (score 0):

If your system has an `/etc/network/interfaces` file, then it's Debian-based and it probably has Network Manager, which a) famously ignores the `interfaces` file and b) runs `dhclient` without being asked, even when a device is running and working the way you want it to.

Newer versions of NetworkManager are supposed to ignore devices that have manual or static configurations. Good luck with that.

Network Manager is great for laptops or any PC with a wifi card. On a desktop PC with LAN-based ethernet, it causes more problems than it solves, IMHO.

Three solutions I have seen, pick the one that most suits:

1. `$ sudo su -c 'echo manual > /etc/init/network-manager.override'`
2. Add the line `NM_CONTROLLED=no` to the device stanza (this seems more RHEL style)
3. `$ sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager`